# Can rpart be applied on mixed data set in R?

Tags: r, data-modeling, na, decision-tree, rpart

I have a dataset with both categorical and numeric attributes. Also, 17% of the data contains missing values. I want to apply decision trees on it. Can rpart function from rpart library in R be applied? is there any alternative package which can handle the mixed data?

Comment: Have you tried running it on your data?

Comment: yes. My target variable is categorical. I used method in rpart as "class". The problem I faced is that the prediction is giving me numerical values where I expected  0 or 1

Comment: Any way you can post some of your data, or some toy data that mimics your data set's structure and reproduces your problem?

Comment: What is the range of those numerical values? If they are between 0 and 1 then they represent probabilities. Why did you expect 0 and 1? Is your target variable binary with classes 0s and 1s?